# Overlaying divs on responsive parent div with background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to achieve is a div container that is responsive but the ability to overlay highlight fields that will stay in the same place based on the parent div.  I want to be able to highlight certain areas of text or form fields but have the form be responsive.  Here's a link to an example: http://www.codeply.com/go/nufYSSEMir

As you can see the highlight div is position: absolute; so obviously it's going to stay exactly where it's at.  I've tried using percents as top and left values but it doesn't scale with the background image.  I have a feeling that my two options are to either have the width as a static value and set the meta viewport to scale to the window size, or get crazy with some JS and maybe jQuery.

Thanks in advance for any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by divix, you need to set `position : relative` to the parent div.
This will tell the browser that your highlight's `position : absolute` is absolute in reference to outerContainer.

Basically any `position:absolute` will look at the first parent that has a position set (whether it's relative, fixed, absolute etc) to calculate top|right|bottom|left offset. If you don't have any parent that has a position set, it will just take the body as a reference

Edit: In order the get the right responsivness try this :

```
body {
    background-color:#ddd;
}

#outerContainer {
    background: transparent url("http://scontent-ord1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpl1/t31.0-8/s960x960/12605534_504076036438839_6108375615162000201_o.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top / 100% auto;
    height: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 742px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
@media only screen AND (max-width:742px){
   #outerContainer {
       height:0;
       padding-top:129.5%;
   } 
}

#innerContainer {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 8%;
    left: 12%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 14%;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: OK, that's definitely a step in the right direction.  I've added that to the sample project.  On the bottom right of the viewport, use the external viewer and shrink the window until the form itself starts to shrink with the width.  For me the highlight field stays in the same spot once the background form starts shrinking.  Maybe solve this with a media query?

Comment: I would rather use % in the top/left and width/height of the highlight. And after that, use a media query to remove the height from the parent div, and use the padding-top hack to get a fixed ratio

Comment: check the edit on my response, for a more human readable proposal! You would have to fix the % to match the one you want for your highlight

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `position: relative;` to the `#outerContainer`, it works for me.